# Get GlobalText in the repeater using QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have an element in QML, something like that

```
        Repeater {
           model : 10
            Rectangle{
                clip: true
                width: 54
                height: 80
                color:"transparent"
            }

            GlobalText { id: textID
                anchors.left: xx.right; 
                anchors.leftMargin: 8
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; 
                text: ""
                font.pointSize: 15
            }
        }
```

And  when I tried to update the first text using this code :

```
textID.children[1].text = "NewText";
```

I got this error :

qrc:qml/test.qml:18: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: textID

Help please.